# Get guid ID of highlighted component in 3d model using autodesk360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

This is my first post on stackoverflow.
I am using autodesk360, uploaded rvt file and got the iframe and display 3d model in my web page.
I want to know when i click on any component within the iframe on 3d model, i want to get the guid id of that component. How can i get that?
Here is the iframe i am using in my web page.
[Screen shot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9fHC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to embed "something like Autodesk 360" on your own web page is by using the Autodesk Forge platform, and more specifically, the [Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/) JavaScript library. And this way you'll also avoid the need to use `<iframe>` which can be tricky to work with.

(Btw. Autodesk 360 is a *product* that's built using the Forge platform as well.)

Look at https://learnforge.autodesk.io if you're interested in some starting pointers in Forge development. There's a tutorial called [View BIM360 & Fusion models](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels) that takes you through the development of a web app that can access and view your designs in BIM360, Fusion Team, or Autodesk 360.

With your Forge app up and running, getting properties of the currently selected component is straightforward. You can simply handle an event when "selection changes", and retrieve the properties of the selected object using the Viewer APIs:

```js
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, function () {
  const selectedIds = viewer.getSelection();
  if (selectedIds.length === 1) {
    viewer.getProperties(
      selectedIds[0],
      function onSuccess(props) {
        console.log(props.externalId); // see if the "external ID" extracted by Forge contains the GUID you're looking for
        console.log(props.props); // or if the GUID is included somewhere in the properties
      },
      function onError(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i want to only view only one model rather than all the folders and all files from the left panel. In iframe it is easy to display only one file rather than all the folders and all files.
I just want to operate only one file.

Comment: The side panel was only included in the Learn Forge sample for convenience. You can simply embed the viewer into your page without any additional UI, only showing a single specified model.

Comment: Can i get any sample example please?
As this is very much needed.
Also is there any way to authenticate any user who wants to view the model without clicking on the button authorize me or Log in button?

Comment: Here is the whole story what i want.
There are different projects which are hosted on our platform and we get rvt files from clients for their projects. We upload to the autodesk360.
Then we want to display 3d model to each client as per their project rvt file. 
We want to have an iframe call the viewer to display the model and once user clicks on any component in the iframe we get it's guid id and match in our own database.
Please help

Comment: Take a look at this simple demo: https://forge-basic-app.herokuapp.com. The source code for it is available at https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app. In this case I don't use any fancy UI. I simply [add the viewer to a div container](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/blob/develop/public/index.html#L22).

Comment: I have managed to configure and manage 3d model viewer using https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/overview.
Now when i upload a file, it is translated and is displayed in the viewer. 
When any of the component is selected/clicked i want to get its GUID ID.
Can you please help?

Comment: I've just updated the answer with more details on how GUID (or other properties) can be retrieved from the viewer.

Comment: Thanks that worked. 
How can i run the forge viewer app without port number. As currently it is running on http://localhost:3000 when i type npm start.
I want to run it like http://localhost/3dviewer.
How can i run this? Please help me its really important.

Comment: When you develop web applications locally, they typically have to run on a custom port. But once you [deploy](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/deployment/) your app somewhere, the custom port is usually not needed anymore.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I deployed the app to the netlify. 
Here is the URL. https://clever-kalam-3284a9.netlify.app/www/
But when i click on the Authorize me it give me no page found.

Comment: In that case the app probably wasn't deployed correctly. The link is trying to redirect to https://clever-kalam-3284a9.netlify.app/api/forge/oauth, but it looks like there's no server running that could handle the request to `/api/forge/oauth`. Try one of the deployment methods suggested in https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/deployment. If you're writing a Node.js server, I'd suggest Heroku.